# relation between arguments of two complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

For any two complex numbers $z_1$ and $z_2$ , if $arg[\frac{z_1}{z_2}] = 0$ then why do we say that $Im[\frac{z_1}{z_2}]= 0$ ?

Comment: If $\arg z=0$ then $\Im z=0$ since $z$ lies on the real axis.

Comment: @Dave But isn’t that for a single complex number ? Here we’re comparing two complex numbers right ?

Comment: But just think of $z=\frac{z_1}{z_2}$ (of course, we assume $z_2\neq 0$).

Comment: @Aditi $\frac{z_1}{z_2}$ *is* a single complex number.

Comment: @Dave oh okay thanks for clarifying!

Comment: @José oh okay thanks ! I thought that it would be the comparison of two complex numbers because $arg[\frac{z_1}{z_2}] = arg(z_1) - arg(z_2)$

Comment: @Aditi - another way of considering it: what does it mean to say that $\arg\left(\dfrac {z_1}{z_2}\right) = \arg(z_1) - \arg(z_2) = 0$? It means they have the same argument $\theta$. That is $z_1 = r_1e^{i\theta}$ and $z_2 = r_2e^{i\theta}$, so $$\frac{z_1}{z_2} = \frac{r_1e^{i\theta}}{r_2e^{i\theta}} = \frac {r_1}{r_2}$$, which is a real number. I.e., the imaginary part is $0$.

Comment: @Paul oh yes ! The Eulerian form makes it a little easier to understand . thanks !